# Having issues Simple VBScript to check if file exists, then copies if not

Tags: vbscript

First off I am not a coder at all so I am probably missing something very basic.

I am writing a script that will run via GPO when our users login to some of our terminal servers to check if a specific file exists in the users home folder, if it does it should exit, if not then it should copy an .ini file from another location. Here is the script I have that is failing.

```
On Error Resume Next

dim shell

set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If  objFSO.FileExists("C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Dynamics SL\solomon.ini") Then

     Wscript.Quit

Else

    objFSO.CopyFile "\\Server\sharepath\file.ini" , "C:\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft Dynamics SL\"


    Wscript.Echo "File Copied."

End If
```

It just displays the File Copied echo when I run the script, no file is copied if the file is not present, and if the file is there it still ticks past it and displays the file copied text.

Edit: Tried to clean up the way it is displayed here on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim strAppDataPath
strAppDataPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%appdata%")
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If .FileExists(strAppDataPath & "\Microsoft Dynamics SL\solomon.ini") Then
         Wscript.Quit
    Else
        .CopyFile "\\Server\sharepath\file.ini", strAppDataPath & "\Microsoft Dynamics SL\"
        Wscript.Echo "File Copied."
    End If
End With
```

Comment: That did it, thanks guys! I knew it was going to be something simple I know what I want to do, I just don't script enough to know the in's and outs of how they work.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use system environment variables within the VB Strings.
expand them beforehand as specified by omegastripes and use concatenate operator to append them to your path.